# Java, my own copy() method would not work

Tags: java, methods, constructor, copy

I am learning java and came upon a small problem, my `copy()` method will not work. I work based on a UML diagram and I am pretty sure that I'm doing everything correctly. Here is the code:

Constructor:

```
public FileName(String name, String extension)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.extension = extension;
  }
```

`copy()` method:

```
public FileName copy()
  {
    return new FileName();
  }
```

The error flashes at the parantheses `FileName()` it says: `'FileName(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' in 'Exam_Practice_4.FileName' cannot be applied to '()'` 

Here is also the UML diagram I'm working with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtSCs.jpg

Would kindly appreciate If I could get some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the looks of it, the class `FileName` does not have a default (aka. parameterless) constructor. We need to pass along parameters `name` and `extension` to the constructor-call when calling it in method `copy()`. --- As an aside: a well-known pattern is to write a [copy constructor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-constructor).

Comment: I see, but than it means that the diagram is incorrect. Am I right?

Comment: No. The Diagram does not show a default constructor.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to this and I don't understand a bit. Isn't the ``` + FileName(name : String, extenssion : String) ``` the default constructor?

Comment: No. As I said: a default constructor is a parameterless constructor. I recommend reading [this tutorial on constructors from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to understand which 'side' those parentheses are for in the diagram. `copy()` means that the copy method **takes no parameters**. It does not mean that all methods or constructors it invokes can't send parameters; those are implementation details that UML diagrams do not include at all. UML diagrams just show you structure, they aren't a replacement for the actual code.

The diagram correctly shows there's only one constructor and it takes 2 parameters.

The `copy` method is an instance method (meaning, it can access the fields), so you'd just write `new FileName(name, extension)`.

For what its worth, designing this as a mutable object is borderline criminal in this day and age, so in that sense, this UML diagram is either from a 20 year old tutorial, or is suboptimal. But it's not *incorrect* as you said in the comments. It accurately reflects a dubious design choice.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. You are right, the university material is very much outdated, I believe this UML diagram was made in 2014-2015.